# E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:961] remapper failed:

Tags: image, tensorflow, jupyter-lab, generative-adversarial-network

the whole error message is:
2024-02-06 15:10:19.270018: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:961] remapper failed: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Mutation::Apply error: fanout 'gradient_tape/sequential/leaky_re_lu_1/LeakyRelu_1/LeakyReluGrad' exist for missing node 'sequential/conv2d/BiasAdd_1'.
this is pop out when i tried to train my GANs model(hist).
here's the code:

```
def build_generator(): 
model = Sequential()

# Takes in random values
# Beginnings of a generated image
model.add(Dense(16*16*512, input_dim=512))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
model.add(Reshape((16,16,512)))

# Upsampling block 1 
model.add(UpSampling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(512, 5, padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

# Upsampling block 2 
model.add(UpSampling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(512, 5, padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

model.add(UpSampling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(512, 5, padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

model.add(UpSampling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(512, 5, padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

model.add(UpSampling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(512, 5, padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))    
# Convolutional block 1
model.add(Conv2D(512, 4, padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

# Convolutional block 2
model.add(Conv2D(512, 4, padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(512, 4, padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(512, 4, padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(512, 4, padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

# Conv layer to get to one channel
model.add(Conv2D(3, 4, padding='same', activation='sigmoid'))

return model

def build_discriminator(): 
model = Sequential()

# First Conv Block
model.add(Conv2D(32, 5, input_shape = (512,512,3)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Second Conv Block
model.add(Conv2D(64, 5))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Third Conv Block
model.add(Conv2D(128, 5))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Fourth Conv Block
model.add(Conv2D(256, 5))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Flatten then pass to dense layer
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

return model 
g_opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001) 
d_opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.00001) 
g_loss = BinaryCrossentropy()
d_loss = BinaryCrossentropy()

    
class GAN(Model): 
    def __init__(self, generator, discriminator, *args, **kwargs):
        # Pass through args and kwargs to base class 
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
    # Create attributes for gen and disc
    self.generator = generator 
    self.discriminator = discriminator 
    
def compile(self, g_opt, d_opt, g_loss, d_loss, *args, **kwargs): 
    # Compile with base class
    super().compile(*args, **kwargs)
    
    # Create attributes for losses and optimizers
    self.g_opt = g_opt
    self.d_opt = d_opt
    self.g_loss = g_loss
    self.d_loss = d_loss 

   
def train_step(self, batch):
    real_images, _ = batch
    batch_size = tf.shape(real_images)[0]
    random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal((batch_size,512))
    fake_images = self.generator(random_latent_vectors, training=False)

    # Resize fake images to match the size of real images
    fake_images_resized = tf.image.resize(fake_images, (512, 512))
    #fake_images_resized = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(fake_images_resized)

    # Concatenate resized fake images with real images
    all_images = tf.concat([real_images, fake_images_resized], axis=0)


    # Labels for real and fake images
    labels_real = tf.ones((batch_size, 1))
    labels_fake = tf.zeros((batch_size, 1))
    all_labels = tf.concat([labels_real, labels_fake], axis=0)

    # Add noise to labels for discriminator
    noise_real = 0.15 * tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(labels_real))
    noise_fake = -0.15 * tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(labels_fake))
    all_labels += tf.concat([noise_real, noise_fake], axis=0)

    # Train the discriminator
    with tf.GradientTape() as d_tape:
        predictions = self.discriminator(all_images, training=True)
        d_loss = self.d_loss(all_labels, predictions)

    # Apply backpropagation for discriminator
    d_grad = d_tape.gradient(d_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_variables)
    self.d_opt.apply_gradients(zip(d_grad, self.discriminator.trainable_variables))

    # Train the generator
    with tf.GradientTape() as g_tape:
        generated_images = self.generator(random_latent_vectors, training=True)
        predictions_fake = self.discriminator(generated_images, training=False)
        g_loss = self.g_loss(tf.ones_like(predictions_fake), predictions_fake)

    # Apply backpropagation for generator
    g_grad = g_tape.gradient(g_loss, self.generator.trainable_variables)
    self.g_opt.apply_gradients(zip(g_grad, self.generator.trainable_variables))

    return {"d_loss": d_loss, "g_loss": g_loss}

    # Create instance of subclassed model
gan = GAN(generator, discriminator)
# Compile the model
gan.compile(g_opt, d_opt, g_loss, d_loss)

    class ModelMonitor(Callback):
    def __init__(self, num_img=3, latent_dim=512):
        self.num_img = num_img
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.uniform((self.num_img, self.latent_dim,1))
        generated_images = self.model.generator(random_latent_vectors)
        generated_images *= 255
        generated_images.numpy()
        for i in range(self.num_img):
            img = array_to_img(generated_images[i])
            img.save(os.path.join('images', f'generated_img_{epoch}_{i}.png'))

hist = gan.fit(train_data, epochs=5, callbacks=[ModelMonitor()])
```